# Line bundles over a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I keep seeing statements like that and I don't know how they might be established:

Let $k \subset \bar{k}$ be fields, $C \rightarrow Spec(\bar{k})$ be a curve and $\mathscr{L}$ a line bundle on $C$. There exist a finite extension $k \subset K$ and a curve $\tilde{C} \rightarrow Spec(K)$ such that $\mathscr{L}$ is also defined over $\tilde{C}$.

Does that mean that in this setting there is always a "nice" curve $\tilde{C} \rightarrow Spec(K)$ such that the map $Pic(\tilde{C}) \rightarrow Pic(C)$ is an isomorphism? How would that "nice" curve be constructed in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What is $L$? Locally it is free of rank one and you have the glueing data (which is given by some maps or if you want by finitely many 1-by-1 matrices). What are the entries? Since $\bar{k}$ is the union of finite extensions of $k$, therefore there is a subfield $K$ so that the finitely many entries live in $K$.

Comment: If $C=Spec(\bar k[X_1, ..., X_n]/(f_1,...,f_s))$ locally, then letting $K$ be the extension of $k$ with the coefficients of $f_i$, we can construct $\tilde C$, which is locally $Spec(K[X_1, ..., X_n]/(f_1,...,f_s))$. Is this what you meant?
Still I don't see a canonical way to carry $\mathscr{L}$ to $\tilde C$.